# Difference between 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0' and implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'

Tags: android, gradle, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, androidx

What is the difference between these 2 implementations in the `build.gradle` dependencies file? Do they both need to be in my Jetpack Compose project if I want to use the `Theme.Material3.DayNight` theme?

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
```

and

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

The first one is the implementation of Material Components for the Android UI based on View System (which uses subclasses of `View` class, layouts, etc).

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android

The second one is the Material Components implementation for Jetpack Compose.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material

Comment: So it looks like both are needed

Comment: I guess so. You need the first one for styling your activity when you declare the theme in AndroidManifest.xml and the second for UI development in general (if your project is 100% compose, otherwise you will need the first one for Material Components in the View based UI)